# How can I fix this error with sklearn.preprocessing?

Tags: python, pycharm, sklearn-pandas

Code:

```py
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [3])
```

resulting in the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'
```

Comment: Did you check the [class signature](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)?. I cannot find any argument named `categorical_features`.

Comment: You need to include the actual code that causes the issue, not just the error message.

Comment: Deprecated since version 0.20: The categorical_features keyword was deprecated in version 0.20 and will be removed in 0.22. You can use the ColumnTransformer instead.

Answer (score 1):

[As Chris said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59639706/how-can-i-fix-this-error-of-sklearn-preprocessing#comment105441399_59639706), the `categorical_features` parameter for [`preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) was deprecated with version 0.20 of scikit-learn. See [the relevant release notes](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/whats_new/v0.20.html#id37), [commit](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/007aa710bd45cd0df8c56ad581a4e59886128771), [pull request](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/10523), and [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10521) for the deprecation. It was then removed in version 0.22. See the [PR](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/13855) and [commit](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/9ee164baa3c0de6678ff0ca61afe75a7e7d586ff) for the removal.